# Can't use USB debugging after ART

Tags: android, adt, usb-debugging, art-runtime

I was testing new Android Run Time (ART), but after that I can't use USB debugging. After that I had changed runtime back do Dalvik and factory reset phone with no success? I also have updated drivers.

Comment: Did you check if the `Enable USB debugging` has remained checked ?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's checked, thanks anyway.

Comment: If you mean adb won't connect at all, I'd be very surprised if this was related.  If you mean that the java debugger won't connect, I could imagine a causal relationship before the factory reset, but less so after.

Comment: Actually, Eclipse don't offer me option to run from device. Emulator works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was checking drivers under **Computer** -> **Manage** -> **Devices** but always got message that my drivers are up to date.

**Here is solution:**

**Eclipse** -> **Android SDK Manager** -> **Install updates** (Google USB Driver)

**NOTE: Before you start installation save Eclipse projects and exit Eclipse.**

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter dos or shell,try using command "adb connect usb" or "adb restart"
2. If the step above dose not work,try using WIFI to debug.Download a adb test app named ADBDEBUG or else，then enter shell,use "adb connect ip:port".
3. Maybe it's useful for you.